# CSS show element when another element is active

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to create a website that displays a list (ol) only when a text input is active/focused

My code looks like the following:

```
<form>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div> some text </div>
               <div>
                  <label>title</label>
                  <input>text input....</input>
                  <div>some text</div>
               </div>
            <div>some text</div>
         </div>
         <ol class="list">
             ...Elements
         </ol>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

It is not possible to remove divs or to put the list in the same div as the input - I have already tried that, it would ruin the layout

I have already tried several things.

The css + operator, so input + list is not working since those two elements don't have the same parent

I have also tried :has, which doesn't work due to bad browser support

Displaying the list at div:hover works but as soon as you move the cursor the list disappers.
It must be visible as long as the input is active/focused

Is this even possible with css or do i need some kind of JavaScript/jQuery stuff?

Comment: Depends on the layout you're after.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```js
$('input').focus(function(){
  $('.list').show();
}).focusout(function(){
    $('.list').hide();
});
```

```css
.list{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div> some text </div>
               <div>
                  <label>title</label>
                  <input>text input....</input>
                  <div>some text</div>
               </div>
            <div>some text</div>
         </div>
         <ol class="list">
             ...Elements
         </ol>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this is wrong, once you focus on the input and the list appears it is not possible to make it disappear again.

Comment: yes, you corrected the problem, but there is another one: .show() and .hide() does the same as opacity css property: the user can actually interact with the element. look at my answer.

Comment: i thought the show&hide does the same thing as display block&none, right ? or am i missing something

Comment: i'm pretty sure it is not, but i am gonna check the documentation, do some tests and tell you

Comment: i am really sorry, you were right. sorry for the missunderstanding

Comment: i see you used a class to control the list, it would be great to do it by toggling it!

Answer (score 1):

Plain javascript can do too, you can add an `id` to the `ol` and `input`.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#test');
let list = document.querySelector('#list');

input.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  toggleList();
})
input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  toggleList();
})

function toggleList() {
  list.classList.toggle('list')
}
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div> some text </div>
        <div>
          <label>title</label>
          <input id="test" />
          <div>some text</div>
        </div>
        <div>some text</div>
      </div>
      <ol id="list" class="list">
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

That works with id and for a single duo input/ol. If you need to repeat inputs/ols a few time, please clarify in your question :)

---

for infos:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: isn't this a bit much elaborated to do such a simple thing?

Comment: @Giuppox well , that's plain javascript, there is no need to load a full library of scripts to simplify the syntax ;) and it keeps HTML/CSS/JavaScript aside from each others. switching a class is a better practice than injecting styles through js.Class can be used by many tag at once also ;)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with pure CSS but you'll need to do some positioning trickery with either the list or the input. Here's a suggestion to show you what I mean:

```html
<form>
   <div>
      <div class="component">
         <div>
            <div> some text </div>
               <div>
                  <label for="input">title</label>
                  <div>some text</div>
               </div>
            <div>some text</div>
         </div>
         <input class="input" id="input" />
         <ol class="list">
           <li>Element 1</li>
           <li>Element 2</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

```css
.component {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 35px;
}
.list {
  display: none;
}
.input:focus + .list {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for. (i am using jquery, remember to import the cdn in the head tag).

---

what @nejc26 suggested i actually **wrong**: he just changes the opacity of the list, but what if in the list there where links? they would be clickable.
in fact the css opacity property just changes the visibility of the element, but giving the user the possibility interact with it.
read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".input").focus(function(){
    $(".list").css("display","block")
  });
  $(".input").focusout(function(){
    $(".list").css("display","none")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<ol class="list" style="display: none">
  <li>Carl</li>
  <li>Peter</li>
  <li>John</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

(to display the result click the button "run code snippet" above)
this, applied to your answer, is something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".input").focus(function(){
        $(".list").css("display","block")
      });
      $(".input").focusout(function(){
        $(".list").css("display","none")
      });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div> some text </div>
               <div>
                  <label>title</label>
                  <input class="input">text input....</input>
                  <div>some text</div>
               </div>
            <div>some text</div>
         </div>
         <ol class="list" style="display: none">
             ...Elements
         </ol>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div>
               <div>
                  <div>
                     <div> some text </div>
                        <div>
                           <label>title</label>
                           <input onfocus="Focus()">text input....</input>
                           <div>some text</div>
                        </div>
                     <div>some text</div>
                  </div>
                  <ol id="list" style="opacity: 0%;">
                      ...Elements
                  </ol>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
         <script>
             function Focus()
             {
                 document.getElementById("list").style.opacity = "100%";
             }
             </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yes. I did have to use some JavaScript.
Have a great day!